# Node/Axios - Function returns axios response to routes

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a question, I don't know if I'm doing it right, I'm sure not, I want to return the answer that the *GetInventory* function gives me from Axios to my default route '/', someone helps me to fix and understand how do i do this?

**Function:**

```
async function getInventory() {
  let res = await axios.get(getInventoryURL);
  let data = res.data;
  return data;
}

let inventory = getInventory();

routes.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.json(inventory);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your code, in this way:

Code:

```
const getInventory = async () => {
     const response = await axios.get(getInventoryURL);
     return response.data;
}

routes.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    return res.json(await getInventory());
});
```

First of all, axios.get creates a [promise](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.1.13/api.html). In other words, it executes asynchronous, so it's important that your code awaits the axios.get promise fulfillment before responds the request.

Att.